# SQL Insert syntax error when I concatenate with "&"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, string-concatenation

I am using visual basic and access.

If I try concatenate with " +" , release the following error: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

My code:

```
 Protected Friend Sub insertarProducto(ByVal codigo As String, ByVal modelo As String, ByVal serial As String, ByVal pallet As String, ByVal precio As Double, ByVal cantidad As Integer, ByVal descripcion As String)
    Try
        con.Open()
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Insert into Productos(Cod_Producto,Serial,Lote/pallet,Modelo,Descripcion,Precio,Cantidad)Values('" & codigo & "','" & serial & "','" & pallet & "','" & modelo & "','" & descripcion & "'," & precio & "," & cantidad & ")", con)
        adapter.Fill(tabla)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Problemas en la consulta: " + ex.Message(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

The order of my columns is good. 
What's going on here?

Comment: Stop concatenating your SQL and use parameterized statements, and you won't have these issues. (Your problem is you're passing a string to a column defined as a floating point type,  or trying to concatenate a floating point with astring and it can't be converted. Use parameters, you'll know exactly which value is being assigned to which param, and you can use floating point values and dates instead of whatever happens to be in a string. You also avoid  issues with SQL injection.) Your question is confusing, BTW - the title says *concatenate with &*, but the first sentence says *with +*.

Comment: Because something happens in the two ways....

Concatenate with &: "SQL Insert syntax error."

Concatenate with +: "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid."

Comment: As I said, don't concatenate and you don't have these issues. The problem is that you're quoting all of your variables when concatenating, and the only ones that should be quoted are those containing strings. Not concatenating and using parameters would allow the DB driver to handle quoting where needed and proper conversion of other values like dates to the proper format, and you avoid all of the silly conversion mistakes and quoting errors.

Comment: To be honest , I've never used parameterized statment .. how I write that statment? :O

Comment: Search here for `[vb.net] parameterized query`. You could put at least **basic effort** into helping yourself when someone draws you a map to the solution, instead of wanting us to do everything for you.

Comment: You're not using VBA, but VB.NET - they are completely different languages despite some syntactic similarities

Comment: Also it appears that `Productos` includes a field named `Lote/pallet`.  Bracket that name in the SQL statement: `[Lote/pallet]`.

Comment: okay Ken sorry. My bad. I will do my best!! Thank u all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(especially Ken ) I obeyed your advice. 
Finally I was able to successfully insert data to my database! First I modified the name of a column (Lote/pallet) and wrote this code:

```
Protected Friend Sub insertarProducto(ByVal codigo As String, ByVal modelo As String, ByVal serial As String, ByVal pallet As String, ByVal precio As Double, ByVal cantidad As Integer, ByVal descripcion As String, ByVal imagen As String)
    Dim cmd As String = "Insert into Productos(Cod_Producto,Serial,Lotpallet,Modelo,Descripcion,Precio,Cantidad,Imagen)Values(@Cod_Producto,@Serial,@Lotpallet,@Modelo,@Descripcion,@Precio,@Cantidad,@Imagen)"
    Try
        con.Open()
        comando = New OleDbCommand(cmd, con)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cod_Producto", codigo)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", serial)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lotpallet", pallet)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modelo", modelo)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descripcion", descripcion)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Precio", precio)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantidad", cantidad)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen", imagen)
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
        comando.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Problemas en la consulta: " + ex.Message(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

This web site help me a lot:
http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/using-parameterized-queries-and-reports-in-vb.net-database-applications.htm

I dont know if was the best way to do it...Thank you so much for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

Use parameterized statements

```
            _command = New SqlCommand
            _command.Connection = connection
            _command.CommandTimeout = 30
             tabla = new dataset()
            _sqlda = New SqlDataAdapter(_command)

            _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cod_Producto", codigo)
            _command.Parameters("@Cod_Producto").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

            _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", serial)
            _command.Parameters("@Serial").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

         and so on..
          _sqlda.Fill(tabla)
```

or

```
      Public Function FillDataSet(query As String, ByVal ParamArray para() As Object) As DataSet

             dim _transaction As SqlTransaction
             Dim _command As SqlCommand

            _command = New SqlCommand(query, yourConnection)

            _ds = New DataSet
            _sqlda = New SqlDataAdapter(_command )
            _command.Transaction = _transaction

            For i = 0 To para.Count - 1
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & i, para(i))
            Next

            _sqlda.Fill(_ds)

           return _ds
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is

OleDbDataAdapter("Insert into Productos(Cod_Producto,Serial,Lote/pallet,Modelo,Descripcion,Precio,Cantidad)Values('" & codigo & "','" & serial & "','" & pallet & "','" & modelo & "','" & descripcion & "'," & precio & "," & cantidad & ")", con)

Try checking the last 2 variables, it seeem that yoy are lacking a single and double quotes. It should look like this:

OleDbDataAdapter("Insert into Productos(Cod_Producto,Serial,Lote/pallet,Modelo,Descripcion,Precio,Cantidad)Values('" & codigo & "','" & serial & "','" & pallet & "','" & modelo & "','" & descripcion & "','" & precio & "','" & cantidad & "' "), con)